# estoy haciendo lo correcto? la idea esque pueda subir multiples archivos png en pygame

Tags: imagen, bucles, clase, pygame, carga

este es el codigo que nose si esta bien

```
import os
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

window_width = 900
window_height = 500

class prueba:
      def __init__(self):
           self.FilesList = []
           self.FilesNumber = 0
           self.FilesFolder = "images/objects"
           self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
           self.running = True


      def Function(self):
           if os.path.isdir(self.FilesFolder):
              os.chdir(self.FilesFolder)
           for files in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
               if  files not in self.FilesList:
                   self.FilesList.append(files)
           imgs = pygame.image.load(self.FilesList[0])
           while self.running:
                 self.screen.blit(self.FilesList[0], [0, 0])
                 for event in pygame.event.get():
                     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        self.running = False

 
           pygame.quit()

 
prove = prueba()
prove.Function()
```

y este es el error que me sale

```
self.screen.blit(self.FilesList[0], [0, 0])
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str
```

Comment: Podrías agregar la etiqueta Python por favor? Así tu pregunta llega a más gente. Digo esto por que eso te podría servir tanto a vos como a aquellos que busquen algo similar a lo tuyo en un futuro.

Comment: ok gracias pero como que ya lo resolvi